# Can someOne help me how to use bridgeKit (objective C to java code )..?

Tags: java, android, ios, apportable

I wanna to convert my iphone application to Android and i'm using apportable sdk for conversion , and i am new to apportable sdk .i read docs of apportable,In that i read  about BridgeKit, and don't know how to use it . How does java file created , how to bridge .m file to java file.. so can someone can suggest me ,from where i should learn and use  bridge kit .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have Java files, there's no need for BridgeKit. Just use Apportable to build your Objective C project for Android.

If you do have Java files you want to add to your Objective C app, see the docs and samples [here](http://docs.apportable.com/using-java.html).

Comment: hey.@paul-beusterien .first of all thanks for reply.Ok i read that documentation and i also  run few sample  regarding it and it works. but i wanna to make a program form scratch . how the res ,scr file are created and how it works.. and also  ,One more question to you.. yesterday i was coding a sample. i used camera functionality .. in that i took pic and wanna to save to android galery  .. but didn't work when i apport my code and vice versa too didn't work   wanna get pic from galery . and use in my code .. so  if you have little knowledge about  it .. please concern me